# It's possible to editing Razor page (.cshtml) in Razor Class Library during debugging without restart? VS 2017

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, razor

I have an `ASP.Net MVC Core application` that references the `Razor class library` that has `SomePage.cshtml`.

When debugging the application, I can edit pages in the application `ASP.Net MVC Core`, and the changes are reflected in the browser (after refreshing).

But when I edit pages in the `Razor Class Library`, the changes are not visible in the browser (after refreshing). I need to stop the application and restart - then the changes will be visible in the browser.

Is there any way to refresh edited pages in the Razor Class Library without restarting?

Comment: I'm going to go with probably not, but here is an interesting article that may be related? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-compilation?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Comment: What files are you making changes to that require restarting?

Comment: @Lukas - I have read it, but they write mainly that `Razor` is compiled, but they don't say anything about refreshing.
After all- the Asp.net mvc application is also compiled, but the changes are visible.

Comment: I edit .cshtml - files that contain "html"

Comment: The Mvc application doesn’t require restarting because IIS recompiles on the fly when you request a page, external dependencies and libraries will not. I’m not well aquatinted with Razor, so I can’t help you with that, sorry!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not possible. In .NET all class libraries must be compiled before executing the code and the compiled reference is included in the original project. So any changes to the class libraries must be compiled again.so we need stop project to compile code and update refrence.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible after installing `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation` package.

Then configure:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddRazorPages();

    services.Configure<MvcRazorRuntimeCompilationOptions>(options =>
    {
        var libraryPath = Path.GetFullPath(
            Path.Combine(HostEnvironment.ContentRootPath, "..", "MyClassLib"));
        options.FileProviders.Add(new PhysicalFileProvider(libraryPath));
    });
}
```

[More details here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-compilation?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio)

Answer (score -1):

You can edit .chtml files without stopping the solution. just need to refresh the page after our correction. if you are using visual studio, c# code too can be edited by changing the settings.
**press shift+f5 for hard refresh**

Comment: this is only true if you are using the ** ASP.Net MVC application **, but in the ** Razor class library ** this is not possible